# google cloud compute engine list of os supported

Tags: operating-system, google-compute-engine

Can someone please confirm me the types of OS image supported on google cloud compute engine. Can I use Solaris 11 and deploy it as a Custom image on the compute engine ?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you can use your own [custom image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#custom_images). In regards to the  types of OS image supported on Google Cloud Compute Engine, I would recommend check [this article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/importing-virtual-disks#supported_operating_systems). Solaris  is not officially supported on Google Cloud Platform at this moment.

Comment: Thanks for answering . So what i got from this , using custom image we can use any OS in the Google cloud . TCO will be of user only and not of Google.

Comment: You can't use any OS image on Google Cloud Platform, please visit [this article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/importing-virtual-disks#supported_operating_systems) which will help you to understand which operating systems are currently supported on Google Cloud Platform